# IE8 Embedding flash in a document ready

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer

I am trying to load a flash movie after the dom content has loaded. For this I use jQuerys document ready functionality. But the flash won't load if it's inside of the document ready. It will load on the outside.

Most basic version of the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
</script>
<body>
    <div id="uploader-1"></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i =1;       
    flashElement = $('#uploader-1');

    var swfVersionStr = "11.1.0";
    var flashvars = {"x": 10, "y": 12};
    var params = {"wmode": "transparent"};
    params.quality = "high";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
    params.allowfullscreen = "false";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "uploader-1";
    attributes.name = "uploader-1";
    attributes.styleclass = "uploader";

    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "flash/Uploader.swf", "uploader-1",
        '1000px', '1000px',
        swfVersionStr, false, 
        flashvars, params, attributes);
    swfobject.createCSS("#uploader-1", "position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 1000px; height:1000px;");
});
</script>
```

If I run this exact code without the doc ready. it works. (also it might be worth mensioning that when inspecting the source the dom is exactly the same) Any suggestions? I tried searching both SO and google but have not found anything similar to this. Issue appears in IE8

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/swfobject/browse_thread/thread/5ec050c79a7b8af6/f7db43d6f7782d38?pli=1) Google Groups discussion, seem to touch the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly solved it. it seemed to be a cache issue loading an old, old, old version of the movie.